# Confused over "vacilar"

Tags: vocabulario

While browsing a few Spanish language forums today, I came across this:

> Un amigo y yo estábamos comentando sobre una foto de nosotros en
>   facebook - de hace tiempo... Otro amigo pensaba que quizás estábamos
>   burlando de el... Es Mexicano y no quiero ofenderle.  ¿Puedo decirle -
>   "No te preocupes... solo es de vacilas!"?

I have always known **vacilar** as Spanish for "*to hesitate or waver*." Now to even consider using **vacilar** in the context mentioned above suggests it has some meaning I am not aware of. Does it? Does it mean "*kidding*" by any chance? If so, how prevalent is the word in that sense? There are other words that mean "*to kid*" more specifically...is **vacilar** preferred over them when that's what one means?

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacilar#Spanish) says it can mean simply "to enjoy" in some parts of Central/South America, but that's not very authoritative.

Comment: In Mexico - A "prank", a "joke" can be considered as a "vacilada". And yes, I'd say "kidding" is a very precise meaning when it comes to most language contexts here in Mexico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RAE, [`vacilar`](http://dle.rae.es/vacilar) also means:

> 5. tr. Engañar, tomar el pelo, burlarse o reírse de alguien.

So in colloquial talking we would say "vacilar" to kind of cheat someone. I do not recall any other word with the same meaning (maybe "engañar", but it has a bigger and more serious connotation), so this is probably the preferred one.

#### Example

Imagine you are telling someone "hey, yesterday I ran a marathon in 2.30 h!" (a very, very good time). Then, the other can tell you "Me estás vacilando, tú no estás tan en forma" (you are teasing me, you are not that fit).

Comment: Umm...that does not fully answer the question.

Comment: Well, the key point here is that "vacilar" is used to cheat or kid someone, yes. I cannot recall any other word with the same meaning, so it is indeed preferred over others.

Comment: If it is in the dictionary, it can no longer be considered slang. It is, nevertheless, an informal or colloquial meaning for the word.

Comment: @Gorpik that is a very fair point. I just replaced it to "colloquial", which is more accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Venezuela we use to say: "un chico se vaciló (o se vacila) a esa chica", to indicate that he seduces a girl without serious intent.

We also say "me vacilé ese paseo" to mean "I enjoyed the ride".

The song "El Nazareno", by Ismael Rivera says:

> "Yo estaba en un vacilón,
>   Fui a ver lo que sucedía.
>   Cuando más me divertía y empezaba a vacilar,
>   No sé de dónde una voz vine a
>   escuchar".

*Vacilón* means "a moment of enjoyment".

A third meaning of "vacilar" (in Venezuela): we use to say "vacílate esta película", i.e. "please watch this movie", the sense in this case is to enjoy without complication.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that vacilar carries a connotation of being somehow *aggressively* kidding someone, or making fun **of**, more than **with** them. I think that the meaning of `vacilar` is closer to **teasing** than to **kidding**.

In your example, and this might be due to a regional variation, I would have said

> "No te preocupes... solo es de **vacile**!"

I mean, you can "*vacilar a alguien*", someone "*te vacila*", but you "*estás de vacile*" (not "*de vacilas*").

Some other ways of saying "I'm kidding you" could be:

- Te estoy tomando el pelo
- Estoy bromeando / Te estoy gastando una broma
- Estoy de [*coña*](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=co%F1a)

All these mean something closer to "I'm joking / I'm kidding" than "I'm making fun of you / teasing you".

Other ways to describe "*vacilar a alguien*" could be:

- Tocar las narices / tocar los huevos
- Incordiar

which, as you can see, have a more aggressive connotation.

Answer (score 2):

In Chile *"vamos a vacilar"* would mean "let's go party/go out/go have fun".

Answer (score 1):

As a Cuban musician, the term vacilar can also mean to enjoy and move the rhythm of the music. I guess in other words, let the music move you.

Comment: OP was not asking for additional meaning of "vacilar" but in a specific context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25835)