# Indefinite 'uno/una' referring to the speaker - can someone explain?

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres, objetos-directos, rae

An example taken from the RAE's DPD 5.2b ([link](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF)):

"...el indefinido 'uno' y su referente es la persona que habla":

> *Si la ven a una vacilar, enseguida se aprovechan*

Can someone please translate this example to English and explain what it means?

Comment: Something like 'If they see you waver, they will take advantage'? But bear in mind I am a native English speaker and we should wait for confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence means something like

> If they see one hesitate, they immediately take advantage of one.

Let's see if I can explain it right. The speaker should talk about herself in the first person, and the sentence should be something like this:

> Si me ven vacilar, ...

But in this case, the speaker is a third person from the point of view of the subject of the sentence (they). So she assumes herself that third person and thus speaks about herself in that way.

> Si la ven...

"If they see her..." Who is her? Oneself. And the word in Spanish to talk about oneself in third person is *uno/una*. So the sentence is

> Si la ven a una vacilar...

The speaker talks about a personal experience, but is probably also advising that it could happen to anyone, so the sentence could also be translated as

> If they see you hesitate...

as mdeway says in his comment. He also notes in another comment that speaking about oneself seems old-fashioned in English, but that's not the case in Spanish, at least in this example.

Comment: One can, of course, in English speak about oneself if one wishes but one generally does not because one risks appearing old-fashioned. Queen Elizabeth II used to do this but her advisers seem to have stopped her. And to satisfy @Carlos curiosity a Mexican colleague used to jokingly refer to me as Don Miguel.

Comment: @mdewey thank you, answer edited :) With some usernames one can never be sure...

Comment: I don't think this is right.  See the Chile and Venezuela answers at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11969/9385.