# ¿Qué significa "vacilar" en Puerto Rico?

Tags: verbos, significado, diferencias-regionales, letras-de-canciones, puerto-rico

Cuando al mayor le da por algo, le da fuerte. Lleva desde el verano cantando cada dos por tres la canción *[Calma](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calma_(canci%C3%B3n))* del cantante puertorriqueño Pedro Capó.

En una parte de la canción se canta lo siguiente:

> Pa vacilar no hay que salir de Puerto Rico.

Obviamente ninguno de los significados que le damos a la palabra en España encaja ahí. Sin embargo, buscando en [el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bEjxKUN) y en [el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vacilar) no encuentro ninguna acepción propia de Puerto Rico. Las que más me encajan son la que da el DLE para otros países cercanos como Cuba: "Gozar, divertirse, hogar" y la propuesta por el DAMER correspondiente a la República Dominicana: "Bailar siguiendo un ritmo."

Por cercanía ganaría esta segunda opción, pero aun así pregunto: ¿qué se entiende por "vacilar en Puerto Rico"?

---

Relacionada, pero no cubre el uso de *vacilar* concreto de Puerto Rico: *[Confused over "vacilar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11969/12637)*

Comment: Otra que me intrigaba más era "abre la medalla", pero después de ver que en realidad era "abre la Medalla" (con mayúscula inicial) ya vi que se refería a una marca de cerveza, como si dijeran aquí "abre la Cruzcampo".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused over "vacilar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/confused-over-vacilar)

Comment: @aparente001 I see this one as specifically asking about Puerto Rico which at the time of writing is not covered in the one you suggest as a duplicate.

Comment: @mdewey - I guess you're right.  I think some secondary answers at the other question threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que se

> **vacilar** es ir de juerga, salir a divertirse festivamente, bailar, gozar, salir de "parranda" o tener una aventura romántica

Tal cómo me confirman amigos de allí, esta [fuente](https://jergozo.com/diccionario-puertoricense/definir/vacilar) señala bien el sentido que se le da en Puerto Rico, que es el de **disfrutar, pasarla bien**

Answer (score 1):

Buscando un poco he encontrado una web llamada *[Tesoro lexicográfico del español de Puerto Rico](https://tesoro.pr/)*, llevada por la [Academia Puertorriqueña de la Lengua Española](https://www.academiapr.org/). Al buscar allí me ha dado el siguiente resultado:

> **[vacilar](https://tesoro.pr/lema/vacilar)**
>
> 1. a. Divertirse o estar de guasa.
> 2. a. (T. en Cuba, Méx. —Guanajuato— y Can.). Burlarse, reírse de una persona sin que esta se dé cuenta; engañar o ilusionar burlonamente a una persona.
>      b. (T. en Guat. y Méx.). Emborracharse a medias.
> 3. a. Ir de juerga.
>      b. Embromar.
>      c. Tomarle a uno el pelo.
> 4. a. Bromear. Charlar jocosamente. Divertirse. Hacer chistes. Festejar. Jugar, entretenerse. Relajar con alguna persona. Tratar de ridiculizar a alguien.

Ahora ya el significado concreto que se le quiera dar al verbo en la canción es otro cantar.

Answer (score 0):

En México vacilar tiene el significado de jugar y divertirse pero también tiene la connotación de *andar de conquista amorosa* o *tener un desliz*. Hay muchas canciones que incluyen la palabra vacilar y aunque es un juego de palabras, el significado está implícito.

De los ejemplos que encontré, todas las canciones tienen un lenguaje mas bien explícito pero la canción *Rico vacilón* del cubano Rosendo Ruiz Quevedo nos dá un ejemplo mas sutil del significado.

> A la china hay que darle cariño
>   A la prieta tremendo apretón
>   A la rubia hay que darle un besito
>   Pero todas gozan el vacilón

En este sentido, los significados que da el DAMER son los mas cercanos en lo que respecta a México.

Answer (score 0):

En Chile...

Vacilar a alguien: reírse, mofarse, o burlarse de alguien

Vacilar con alguien: pasar el rato sin hacer nada productivo, o sólo divirtiéndose

Vacilar con alguien del sexo opuesto: estar insinuándose, o estar en algo no muy serio aún con la otra persona

Vacilón o vacileo: la fiesta, la parranda

Alguien vacilón: alguien que no muestra respeto, que se rie o mofa de otros.

no vaciles: no jorobes, no jodas (dirían los españoles)

salgamos a vacilar: vamos a pasarlo bien por ahí